# display future date with moment.js

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs, future

I'm trying to use http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/ to show the day (Monday), the month (July) and the number date (20) four days in the future. so basically I'm trying to do today+4 and to display day, month, #. i knew jquery was the best bet when i came upon moment.js

i put the

```
<script src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script>
    moment().format();
</script>
```

in my footer like the instructions said and I'm using

```
<p class="day"><script>document.write(moment().add(4, 'day'));</script></p>
```

to try and display it. this part is just for the "Friday" part cause I'm still trying to figure out how to do the month and number date, but I'm thinking help with this part may really help with the other two.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: ok so i put the stuff from the footer into the header and now stuff is displaying...that was such a rookie mistake...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var fourDaysForward = new moment().add(4, 'day');
document.write(fourDaysForward.format('dddd MMMM DD'));
```

Comment: i tried doing 
var today = new moment();
var fourDaysForward = moment.add(4, 'dddd');
document.write(fourDaysForward);
but nothing showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.format()` with the appropriate arguments. [See docs here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Thus, I *think* you're looking for `moment.format('dddd MMMM D')`

Comment: I think my biggest problem is nothing. not even an error, is showing up. but this was helpful with displaying, thank you.

Comment: No problem. I hope that at least a little helpful